# Show that sum of integral of $f_n$ converges

Tags: integration, uniform-convergence

I want to show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int |f_n(x)|dx$ converges if $f$ is integrable with $f_n(x)=f(a_nx)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges. Here, $a_n$ is positive and integral is on $\mathbb{R}$.

I try to use the theorems in my course, so I think I can permute the sum and the integral, but I don't have many informations on $f_n$ so it's a little bit difficult. Can you help me ?

Comment: I don't understand the mathematical expressions you ve written

Comment: Abs is for absolute value and fi is a suite of fonctions (I can rewrite sum on  n of integral on R of absolute value of fn(x), sorry I didn't found it on the help section

Comment: Prove that $\sum_{0}^n \int \Bbb  |f_n(x)|dx$ converges if f is integrable and $f_n(x)=f(a_n\cdot x)$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n 1/a_n$ converges?

Comment: fix formatting please. and spelling errors. and grammar errors.

Comment: Yes hypernova thank you

Comment: What's the limits of integration?

Comment: I edited the question to the best of my ability. Feel free to change it (ie, add limits of integration) if this isn't your question.

Comment: Thank you for edits, it's the right bounds of integral